# R data.table: merge fails when key values contain special characters (ü, ö, ä)

Tags: r, special-characters, data.table

I'm trying to merge two data tables. The merge works well on `merge.data.frame`, but not with `merge.data.table`. May it have to do with the special characters that I'm using? I obtain the `data.tables DT1` and `test2` through several processing steps before. The problem does NOT occur when I enter the data from `test2` and `DT1` manually:

```
> test2 
               lfm_id lfm_plays
1: Herbert Grönemeyer       115
> DT1
               lfm_id value
1: Herbert Grönemeyer     5
> class(test2) # check objects
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(DT1)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(test2$lfm_id) # check column types
[1] "character"
> class(DT1$lfm_id)
[1] "character"
> merge(DT1, test2, by='lfm_id') 
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: lfm_id,value,lfm_plays
# merge failed!

# trying with the 'old' data.frame merge:
> merge.data.frame(DT1, test2, by='lfm_id')
              lfm_id value lfm_plays
1 Herbert Grönemeyer     5       115
# works!

# the keys match, too:
> DT1$lfm_id==test2$lfm_id
[1] TRUE
```

I use `R 2.15` and `data.table v. 1.8.8`.
The two objects (test2 and DT1) are available for [download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4900810/stackoverflow_data.RData).

Comment: Encoding issue... I noticed that the strings (Herbert Grönemeyer) convert to different raw values, using charToRaw(): Herbert GrÃ¶nemeyer vs Herbert Grönemeyer. That's why the chmatch function in data.table couldn't match them. I solved the problem by using the same encoding for both types of character columns / factors. It may be a bit naive, but this works fine for me: new.encode <- function(x) {
 if (class(x)=='factor') {
  out<-x
  levels(out) <- iconv((enc2native(as.character(levels(out)))))
  return(out)
  } else {
  return(iconv((enc2native(x))))
  }
  
 }

Comment: Instead of posting your answer as a comment, why not post it as an answer so that others with a similar problem will be able to easily see that it has been answered.

Comment: without reproducible example we cannot even verify it if has been fixed in last 7 years since question was asked